# Print only alphabetics in a string using Regular Expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

Goal : i want only alphabets to be printed in a string

```
#Input 
#======
string = '   529Wind3@.     '

#Neededoutput
#============
'Wind'
```

I tried coding for this using the below code

```
import re
string=re.sub('[^a-z]+[^A-Z]',' ',string)
print(string)
```

The output i'm getting is

```
ind
```

But this code only applies for lowercase
Can you please tell me how to write code for both upper and lowercase

Comment: I suggest you to not use regex

Comment: You could just do `''.join([i for i in String if i in string.ascii_letters])`

Comment: Note that you also have to import `string`

Comment: @U8-Forward - why not put this as an answer, not a series of comments? imo, would have looked better as a whole block

Comment: Please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `[^a-zA-Z]` instead of `[^a-z]+[^A-Z]`. The `+` operator is for detecting repetitive characters and not to combine multiple conditions.

Try the below code for your requirement:

```
import re
string=re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ',string)
print(string)
```

Comment: Yup. I noticed it now. But the Slideshow's answer does not explain why the "+" operator is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @U8-Forward's point but I think you may also want to know why your regular expression isn't working. This

```
[^a-z]+[^A-Z]
```

doesn't do what you want because `W` matches `[^a-z]+` and so gets removed.

Put all of the characters you don't want in a single character class:

```
[^a-zA-Z]+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a list comprehension to check if each character is in `string.ascii_letters` or not, if it is, it will be stored:

```
import string
String = '   529Wind3@.     '
print(''.join([i for i in String if i in string.ascii_letters]))
```

Output:

```
Wind
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
import re
String = '   529Wind3@.     '
string = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', String)
print(''.join(string))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','',string)
```